# Wifi or Wireless fidelity in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, technology

Salvē!
I am new here and searched the questions, but could not find anything.
In another site somebody suggested: *interrete trans spiritum*, but this seems too long. Maybe a catchy abbreviation such as *wifi* but using the words in Latin?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12):

[The name Wi-Fi never was an abbreviation of "wireless fidelity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi#Etymology_and_terminology).
Therefore I see two approaches to naming it in Latin:

1. Use Wi-Fi as a name.
2. Express the idea "wireless network access" somehow.

In the first approach the name would be indeclinable, so there is no case inflection.
Cases can be expressed by an auxiliary word (*possimne uti Wi-Fi tuo?*) or the syntactic role can be clarified with prepositions (*per Wi-Fi interrete adhibemus*) word order or other similar structure (*visne Wi-Fi?*).

In the second approach there is no reason to translate the word "fidelity" in any way.
The basic question is to find a good translation for "wire" or "cable".
The second one seems to come from the Latin *capulum*.
Using that, we could say ***rete decapulatum***, "a wireless net".

Both approaches have their merits.
The first one is at least very simple to use and understand, so that would be my first recommendation.

Answer (score 8):

To me, *wifi* feels like a word that the Romans would have just borrowed rather than used their own phrase for. If you swap out the *W* for a *V* and treat it like a third declension noun, you get *vifis* as the genitive noun. I'm not sure how awkward that would sound to those more experienced than me, though. I suppose it's better than *vaefae*, though. :)

Comment: For some reason *vaefae* sounds more like a waffle to me.

Comment: That's how we do it in Czech (`/vIfI/`) be we do not decline it. We do decline the colloquial wifina though (`/vIfIna/`).